# href=tel: Funciona de forma intermitente

Tags: html, html5

Buen dia, tengo en el index de mi pagina el siguiente pedazo de codigo:

```
  <div class="col-sm-3 claseHome">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      <a href="tel:11111111"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone">
       </span>111-1111</a>
     </button>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center"><a href="foto.pdf" 
     target="_blank"><img src="img/foto.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
       <a class="nota" href="anterior.php"><strong>HOLA</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Y mi problema es que, cuando abro la pagina en el celular, para que funcione el boton de llamada (es decir, para que me redireccione al telefono con ese numero), tengo que clikear varias veces.
A veces funciona bien, otras no responde hasta la quinta o sexta vez que lo toco.
Podrian ayudarme?
Gracias!

He probado en varios celulares con distintos sistemas operativos y distintas versiones y pasa lo mismo en todos.

Comment: No deberías meter un enlace dentro de un botón

Comment: ¿Por que usas esa forma? ¿No has usado un **input** del tipo **tel**? < input id="telNo" type="tel">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en que estas usando un boton

Deberías usar un etiqueta link `<a>` para poder que el teléfono entienda que debe realizar una acción

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="tel:11111111"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"> </i>111-1111</a>
```